# what does -X option do with git pull?

Tags: git, git-pull

```
git pull origin -X theirs branch_name
```

What does `-X theirs` do in this git pull command? Does it cause the specified branch to be merged into the current branch?

Answer (score 4):

[`-X`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt--Xltoptiongt) specifies the merge strategy ***option*** (not to be confused with the [merge ***strategy***](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt--sltstrategygt)) when combining your local changes with changes pulled from upstream. You can read up on the different merge strategies in the [official `git` documentation](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#_merge_strategies). By default the `ort` strategy is used, so the below options are relevant to this:

- [`ours`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt-ours): This option forces conflicting hunks to be auto-resolved cleanly by favoring `our` version.
- [`theirs`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt-theirs): The opposite of `ours`. Auto-resolve using `their` version.
- [`ignore-space-change`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt-ignore-space-change), [`ignore-all-space`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt-ignore-all-space), [`ignore-space-at-eol`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt-ignore-space-at-eol), [`ignore-cr-at-eol`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt-ignore-cr-at-eol): Treats lines with the indicated type of whitespace change as unchanged for the sake of a three-way merge.
- [`renormalize`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt-renormalize): This runs a virtual check-out and check-in of all three stages of a file when resolving a three-way merge.
- [`no-renormalize`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt-no-renormalize): Disables the `renormalize` option. This overrides the `merge.renormalize` configuration variable.
- [`find-renames[=<n>]`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt-find-renamesltngt), [`rename-threshold=<n>`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt-rename-thresholdltngt): Turn on rename detection, optionally setting the similarity threshold. This is the default. `rename-threshold` is a deprecated synonym of `find-renames`.
- [`subtree[=<path>]`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt-subtreeltpathgt): This option is a more advanced form of subtree strategy. See the link for more information on this one.

Some of the descriptions above were copied from the `git-pull` documentation.

Comment: Note: the `-s ort` strategy is pretty new. A large number of people will get the old `-s merge-recursive` default strategy. It has the same `-X` options though (I like to call them "eXtended options", to keep this straight in my head, rather than the confusing "merge strategy option" three-word-but-one-unit-thing-for-`-X` that's different from the `-s` merge strategy option that's not for `-X`.  )